# IVY resolver is looking in different local path

Tags: ivy

I have defined local cache as below :

```
<caches defaultCacheDir="${user.home}/.ivy2/local"
  ivyPattern="[organization]/[module]/[module]-[revision]/[module]-[revision]-ivy.xml"
  artifactPattern="[organization]/[module]/[module]-[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
```

and trying to fetch data using resolver as

```
<resolvers>
  <chain name="chain1" changingPattern=".*SNAPSHOT" returnFirst="true">
  <resolver ref="local"/>
  <ibiblio name="maven-repo1"
```

I have already all the jars in my local. But for a number of jars it is not able to find them as IVY is looking them in different path as below:

```
[ivy:resolve]       module not found: org.apache.cxf#cxf-rt-core;2.2.+
[ivy:resolve]   ==== local: tried
[ivy:resolve]     C:\Users\psaha\.ivy2/local/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-        core/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]     [ivydata-2.2.12.properties, ivydata-2.2.+.properties, cxf-rt-core-2.2.12]
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.cxf#cxf-rt-core;2.2.+!cxf-rt-core.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     C:\Users\psaha\.ivy2/local/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-core/[revision]/jars/cxf-rt-core.jar
[ivy:resolve]     [ivydata-2.2.12.properties, ivydata-2.2.+.properties, cxf-rt-core-2.2.12]
[ivy:resolve]       module not found: org.apache.cxf#cxf-rt-frontend-simple;2.2.+
[ivy:resolve]   ==== local: tried
[ivy:resolve]     C:\Users\psaha\.ivy2/local/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-simple/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]     [ivydata-2.2.12.properties, ivydata-2.2.+.properties, cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.2.12]
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.cxf#cxf-rt-frontend-simple;2.2.+!cxf-rt-frontend-simple.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     C:\Users\psaha\.ivy2/local/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-simple/[revision]/jars/cxf-rt-frontend-simple.jar
[ivy:resolve]     [ivydata-2.2.12.properties, ivydata-2.2.+.properties, cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.2.12]
[ivy:resolve]       module not found: org.apache.cxf#cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws;2.2.+
```

and ideally I do not want ivy to look into places like ../ivys/.. or ../jars/..
This is happening only for a couple of jar/ivy resolution. How to fix this issue?

Comment: You haven't specified enough information to investigate this issue. Please supply your complete ivysettings.xml file. Additionally, unlike Maven, ivy caches are not the same as local repositories. I suspect this would explain your build output.

Comment: I found out the issue. It seems if ivy.xml contains dependencies like this: `<dependency org="net.sourceforge.jtds" name="jtds" rev="1.+"/>
    <dependency org="com.oracle" name="ojdbc14" rev="10.+"/>` ivy goes to the extrnal repo to look out for newer updates irrespective of if some versions are available in local cache.

Comment: Yes, look at the dependency declaration. You've specified "1.+".... In order to determine if a later revision is available, ivy must go to the repository.